# Cumulative normal distribution funciton in Excel

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, function

I am looking for help to calculate a CDF for a multinominal distribution function. (I'm strictly using Excel)

I have figured out, how to calculate the bivariate distribution, but seems to be a lot more complicated adding more dimensions.

I have 5 variables.

Comment: Welcome to SE. What do you mean by CDF? The probability density for the parameters of the multinomial distirbution, given data? That would be handeled by [Dirichlet Distirbution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). Or the probability mass function for the multinomial itslef, given data? That would be handeled by [Dirichlet-Multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution). Perhaps if you showed what was a good result for you in case of binomial distribution, it would be easier to give you a good answer

Comment: Or the multivariate normal? (The multinominal would be, I suppose, a multivariate nominal distribution, but I wouldn't expect to see meaningful tables there, if only because the order of cumulation would be totally arbitrary.)

Comment: You can find references to solutions at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32156/how-to-evaluate-a-multivariate-gaussian-condition/91035#91035.  Unless you are a true expert at VBA in Excel as well as in numerical algorithms, please don't even attempt this in Excel: use software, such as `R`, where knowledgeable programmers have already implemented and tested solutions.

Comment: What I mean by CDF is the Cumulative Distribution Function for a given probability density function. That is, a function that provides the volume / area under the given function (i.e., the integral from 0 to X,Y,Z of the joint distribution function)